# Freemarker regex

Tags: java, regex, freemarker

I am trying to check if input is number or not. Here's the code

```
<#if (link_data.canonical)!?matches(".*/sites/.*") && (pageData.ar.gP)?has_content >
<#if (pageData.ar.gP)?is_number >
    <link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/${(pageData.ar.gP)!}" />
<#else>
    <link rel="ar" href="https://plus.google.com/+${(pageData.ar.gP)!}" />
</#if>
</#if>
```

However the above din't work well for me. So I'm trying to write a regex to check if the value of pageData.ar.gP matches ([A-Za-z]). Below is the code

```
<#if (link_data.canonical)!?matches(".*/sites/.*") && (pageData.ar.gP)?has_content && (pageData.ar.gP)?matches("A-za-z")>
   <link rel="ar" href="https://plus.google.com/+${(pageData.ar.gP)!}" />
<#else>   
    <link rel="ar" href="https://plus.google.com/${(pageData.ar.gP)!}" />
</#if>
```

The above code also does not seem to work. What's wrong in it?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: it does not detect a number. even if I do ?is_number nor does it detect the regex ?matches("A-za-z"). If pageData.ar.gP is a number I don't want to append + in the url . If pageData.ar.gP is non-number I want to append + in the url.

Comment: `?is_number` checks if its left-hand operand has numerical type, not if it's a string that could be interpreted as a number. So you will have to use a regexp there too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience on your `freemarker`. So I am only talking about your `regex` here.

Your regex has several mistakes.

- You didn't place them inside the character class `[]`
- Inside character class `A-z` means all characters from capital `A` to lower `z`. So it should be `A-Za-z`
- You need to place a `+` to repeat your match for 1 or more characters like `[]+`

So finally it will be:

```
(pageData.ar.gP)?matches("[A-Za-z]+")
```